# scrollview scrolls up while accessing last component of view controller

Tags: ios, scrollview

I am fresher in iOS Development domain.

I placed scollview on Prooduct Detail ViewController, on this scollview placed product image, product details, add to cart button, and lastly recommended product list in collection view which scrolls horizontal.

My issue is that, when it scrolls down to view controller & tries to access collection view, it scrolls up because of that i can’t access collection view.

Here's my UI:

[image]

Comment: In default scroll view is a super class of collection view.You don't need to add any scroll view for collection view.

Comment: Can you show the view design?

Comment: attached screenshot.

Comment: what does it happen when you do not add the scroll view on Product detail view controller??

Comment: it doesn't shows collection view (recommended product )if I'am not placing scrollview. And when i use scrollview ,then it shows all components properly but when i try to scroll collection view horizontally ,scroll view scrolls up .

Comment: If you are going to add collection view inside the scroll view,don't set the collection view.Collection view is subclass of UIScroll view

Comment: Without collection view you can do this.

Comment: I help you but i need a time.

Comment: okey take your time but let me know its solution.thnks

Comment: Okey definitely I will do this.

Comment: Does below answer work for you?

Comment: Do you not need another solution from me?

Comment: sure i would like it if u can ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
```

As per the apple documentation the automaticAdjustScrollViewInsets by default YES.

So its trying to control your scrollview.

add this in your viewdidload method and then try.

Comment: please explain the down vote  , then i will improve my answer

Comment: I have not down voted your answer.Someone  down voted your answer.

Comment: You answer whether it is correct or not it depends on the questioner.I have not tried your answer.

Comment: @KishoreKumar she is not able to comment on this dont know why , she want to talk , can you say why this happen , may be her reputation is low.

Comment: i tried to comment but it wont sent to both of you.

Comment: @snehalrokade  refer this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html visit his link ,i am not sure why apple set by default yes.